# Delete Linked List Function

Tags: c

Here's my function to delete a linked list:

```
void deleteList( NODE* head )
{
    NODE* temp1; 
    NODE* tempNext;
    temp1 = head;
    tempNext = NULL;

    while( temp1 != NULL )
    {
        tempNext = temp1->next;
        free(temp1);
        temp1 = tempNext;
    }
}
```

So temp1 first points where the head pointer is pointing. If it isn't `NULL`, `tempNext` will be set to point to the next element of the list. Then the first element (`temp1`) is free'd, and `temp1` is reassigned to point to where `tempNext` is pointing and process repeats.

**Is this the right approach to deleting an entire list?**

I ask this because when I print the list after using this function, it still prints the list. And IIRC freeing something doesn't delete it but only marks it as available so I'm not sure how to tell if this is correct or not.

Comment: It also depends on how your list looks like. If you've allocated memory for the data (if your list contains a pointer to data) then you might want to free that one too and just not the list that keeps a reference to it.

Comment: @Jite: Oh good point~! I'll keep that in mind for the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks correct.

You're also correct that freeing a list's elements doesn't immediately change the memory they pointed to.  It just returns the memory to the heap manager which may reallocate it in future.

If you want to make sure that client code doesn't continue to use a freed list, you could change `deleteList` to also NULL their `NODE` pointer:

```
void deleteList( NODE** head )
{
    NODE* temp1 = *head;
    /* your code as before */
    *head = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Just notice `pointer-to-pointer` as argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

It still print the list, because you probably don't set the `head` pointer to `NULL` after calling this function.

Answer (score 1):

`I ask this because when I print the list after using this function, it still prints the list.`

There is a difference between `free`ing a pointer and invalidating a pointer. If you `free` your whole linked list and the head, it means that you no longer "own" the memory at the locations that `head` and all the `next` pointers point to. Thus you can't garintee what values will be there, or that the memory is valid.

However, the odds are pretty good that if you don't touch anything after freeing your linked list, you'll still be able to traverse it and print the values.

```
struct node{
    int i;
    struct node * next;
};

...
struct node * head = NULL;
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head->i = 5;
head->next = NULL;
free(head);
printf("%d\n", head->i); // The odds are pretty good you'll see "5" here
```

You should always free your pointer, then directly set it to NULL because in the above code, while the comment is true. It's also dangerous to make *any* assumptions about how `head` will react/contain after you've called `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but maybe it'll help someone performing a search on the topic.

This is what I recently wrote to completely delete a singly-linked list.  I see a lot of people who have heartburn over recursive algorithms involving large lists, for fear of running out of stack space.  So here is an iterative version.

Just pass in the "head" pointer and the function takes care of the rest...

```
struct Node {
    int i;
    struct Node *next;
```

};

```
void DeleteList(struct Node *Head) {

    struct Node *p_ptr;

    p_ptr = Head;

    while (p_ptr->next != NULL) {
            p_ptr = p_ptr->next;
            Head->next = p_ptr->next;
            free(p_ptr);
            p_ptr = Head;
    }

    free(p_ptr);
```

}